# Using GACUTIL in Post-build event in Visual Studio on Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, gacutil

I have a Visual Studio 2012 project that creates an SSIS custom task. In the Post-build event, I have this:-

```
cd $(ProjectDir)
@SET TASKDIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Tasks\"
@SET GACUTIL="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\gacutil.exe"
Echo Installing dll in GAC
Echo $(OutDir)
Echo $(TargetFileName)
%GACUTIL% -if "$(OutDir)$(TargetFileName)"
Echo Copying files to Tasks
copy "$(OutDir)$(TargetFileName)" %TASKDIR%
```

which used to work with Windows 7.

Today, for the first time, I have tried to do this on Windows 10 and I'm getting:-

> Failure adding assembly to the cache: Administrator permissions are
> needed to use the selected options.

If I start a command window as Administrator and use the command:-

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\gacutil.exe" -if "C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SSISCompressionTask\SSISCompressionTask\bin\Debug\<Task Name>.dll`

it works.

How do I continue to put the assembly in the GAC from the Post-build event in Visual Stusio please?

Thanks

Comment: If you launch your Visual Studio as an administrator, does that allow the post build step to GAC your assembly?

Comment: Good question, I don't know. I'll give it a try and let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I started Visual Studio as an administrator and that now allows me to install the dll in the GAC and to copy the files to the Tasks folder which, I hadn't mentioned, wasn't working either.

If you want to ensure Visual Studio always runs as administrator,

Start Menu -> More -> Open file location

[image: Start Menu -> More -> Open file location]

Right click on the file and select properties. In this Shortcut tab, select `Advanced...`

[image: Click Advanced...]

In the Advanced Properties window, check the "Run as administrator" button

[image: Check run as administrator]

Ok, Ok and now you've modified the shortcut to always launch Visual Studio as an administrator.